# Simple PHP login script

Tags: php, authentication

I'm looking for a simple secure script that i can add to my website (run on iis 7), which will allow users to create accounts, login, and logout.
Thanks

Comment: here you go dear. http://bit.ly/HlcQNj

Comment: better one here: http://www.php-login.net

Answer (score 2):

**Example :**

[A simple Login Script in PHP](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/tlddl-php-simple-login-tutorial-learn-simple-login.html)